# Regarding Service Locator Pattern

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, service-locator

Service Locator seems like a pretty useful concept and I'd like to implement it in my app. However, I have a few questions about how it should be implemented and how it should be used in conjunction with other programming paradigms.

1. Should the SL manage the service it is storing? That is, when the SL gets destroyed, should it also destroy the service itself, or should it leave that to whoever registered the service?
2. What about Dependency Injection? Now that I have an SL is there any point in passing the SL around as a parameter or should I access it globally? After all, much of the whole purpose of DI is covered by SL as well, and I wouldn't like to clutter a lot of my functions with *one more parameter*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would think I wrote this article (I didn't), considering how often I refer to it:

[Service Locator is an Anti-Pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx)

Dependency Injection makes your dependencies explicit.  Service Location buries them in the implementation, and creates a hard dependency on your locator.

Comment: Great article for C# and Java but not so great fot C++. C++ offers constructs (for example overloaded new and delete operators) with no way to inject dependency.

Comment: The article is about java - not c++, therefore not very useful.

Comment: IMHO, this article is not good, at least not in C++. It's all about the service locator returning an invalid reference when not prepared to do so. First, a locator in C++ (e.g. [EnTT's locator](https://github.com/skypjack/entt/blob/2f51341633aba7a37af9208af80c9a596a205a4e/src/entt/locator/locator.hpp) via `value_or`), can return a default implementation, as C++ is not Java and we don't always use interfaces. Alternatively, one could create a Locator which could be passed as `Locator<T1, T2, T3>` in the constructor to assert that those types exist in the locator and document the dependency.